# Painting the fence

Tags: c++, algorithm

The problem statement is:

Given a fence with n posts and k colors, find out the number of ways of painting the fence so that not more than two consecutive posts have the same colors. Since the answer can be large return it modulo 10^9 + 7.

Example Testcases

n = 3
k = 2
Output: 6

n = 2
k = 4
Output: 16

The code I have written is

```
long long countWays(int n, int k){
    if(n==1)
    {
        return k;
    }
    long long ans;
    long long mod=1000000007;
    long long same=k%mod;
    long long diff=(k*(k-1))%mod;
    for(int i=3;i<=n;i++)
    {
        long long temp=diff%mod;
        diff=(((diff+same)%mod)*(k-1)%mod)%mod;
        same=temp%mod;
    }
    return (same+diff)%mod;
}
```

This code is running successfully for most of the part but it is failing the test case n=27608 k=99118 for which the output should have been 108753863 but the output is coming 340817251.

I think the problem might be with modulo 10^9 + 7.

I tried everything but nothing seems to work.

Comment: *I tried everything but nothing seems to work* What did you try? And explain your code, it's cryptic.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because its asking someone to solve an interview question!

Comment: This is not an interview question, its just a POTD from GFG

Comment: In future use UB sanitizer: https://godbolt.org/z/f1sd1TzGz it points exactly where problem is.

Comment: Aside from the modulo business, what is the underlying argument for counting the desired number of combinations?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Hey so the problem in your code is at the line where you are defining 'diff' variable.

```
class Solution
{
    public:
    long long countWays(int n, int k)
    {
        if(n==1)
        {
            return k;
        }
        long long ans;
        long long mod=1000000007;
        long long same=k%mod;
        long long diff=((long long)(k)*(k-1))%mod;
        for(int i=3;i<=n;i++)
        {
            long long temp=diff%mod;
            diff=(((diff+same)%mod)*(k-1)%mod)%mod;
            same=temp%mod;
        }
        return (same+diff)%mod;
    }
};
```

As k is passed inside the function as an 'int' type variable, (k*(k-1)) is stored as int and that leads to the wrong answer testcase.
To remove that error, you can cast it as long long by
`(static_cast<long long>(k)*(k-1))` or simply `((long long)(k)*(k-1))`. This way, the value of (k*(k-1)) will be stored as long long.

Hope that helps.

Comment: Just keep trying. You will get there. Make sure to keep an eye on the preview while editing That will save you making several intermediate tests visible to everybody.

Comment: Did you consider using `1ll` or maybe better `1LL` somewhere?

Comment: The indentation is off. Can you correct?

Comment: No @Yunnosch . I don't think it's required in this problem

Comment: Is it good now @trincot?

Comment: Yes, that's fine!